# How Can I split one textbox into multiple textbox by paragraph

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I could not find any information through google about splitting textbox to multiple textboxes, I want my all text will be divided by paragraph with new textboxes for each paragraph. their position will be the same, can anyone help me giving the code or tell me the way to complete the macro in powerpoint

Comment: `myArray = Split(multiParagraphTextHere, vbLf)` then loop over `myArray` and place each element in a separate textbox.   Please review [ask] and consider updating your question, otherwise it's likely to get closed.  You need to tell us what the *specific* issue is that you're facing when trying to write this code.

Comment: Try googling _powerpoint vba split textbox by paragraph_.